# How to get an array of uint with web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am curently working on a solidity project along with a web3js client. I made this procedure in my contract, ddployed it in my testrpc and made a client request using web3js.

The problem is in the response, I expected a simple array of uint like [1,2,3]
but got a strange response that even if it holds the desired response it is still not the one i needed.

here is the response :

```
[…]
   0: {…}
       c: Array [ 12355678 ]
       e: 7
       s: 1
   __proto__: Object { abs: another/P.abs(), absoluteValue:   another/P.abs(), ceil: another/P.ceil(), … }
   length: 1
   __proto__: Array []
```

here is the solidity function :

```
function getAllClientsOfABank(bytes32 BankName) returns(uint[]) {
    uint[] memory Clientss = new uint[](Banks[BankName].numberOfClients);

    for(uint i = 0; i < Banks[BankName].numberOfClients; i++) {
        Clientss[i]=Banks[BankName].Clients[i].cin;

    }
    return Clientss;
}
```

**Note** : cin is a uint type / Banks is a mapping of strings and BankStruct / Clients is a mapping of uint and ClientStruct

**Web3JS Client Call **

```
 contractInstance.getAllClientsOfABank.call('BAN556',{gas:3000000}).then(
     data => {
          console.log(data);
              }
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the response by pulling from `c`.

Unfortunately, for arrays, you have to map them together.

So if you're expecting `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then you'd have to do something like this:

```
let arr = data.map(res => res.c[0])
```

If the array has arrays, then:

```
let arr = result.map(res => res.map(res => res.c[0]))
```

...and so forth.